# Geojson in Ipython display cannot be imported in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to know why the copy-pasted example from the Iphython.display Geojson won't import in Jupyter notebook.

```
from IPython.display import GeoJSON

GeoJSON(data={
     "type": "Feature",
     "geometry": {
         "type": "Point",
         "coordinates": [-81.327, 296.038]
     }
 },
 url_template="http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/whereonmars.cartodb.net/{basemap_id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
 layer_options={
     "basemap_id": "celestia_mars-shaded-16k_global",
     "attribution" : "Celestia/praesepe",
     "minZoom" : 0,
     "maxZoom" : 18,
 })
```

The above example gives the error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-138cfbb20fb9> in <module>()
----> 1 from IPython.display import GeoJSON
      2 
      3 GeoJSON(data={
      4      "type": "Feature",
      5      "geometry": {

ImportError: cannot import name GeoJSON
```

Using `pip list` these are the installed versions:

```
ipykernel (4.5.2)
ipython (5.1.0)
ipython-genutils (0.1.0)
ipywidgets (5.2.2)
```

According to their git discussion it should be added right?: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/10253

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!