# from IPython.display import GeoJSON not working on google colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, google-colaboratory, geojson

On Google Colab I'm getting an error when trying to import GeoJSON from IPython.display:

[image]

Any help on how to properly import it would be appreciated.

Comment: Here's another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45558954/geojson-in-ipython-display-cannot-be-imported-in-jupyter-notebook) where the same issue was encountered about 3 years ago. It appears to have been fixed in this [PR](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/10253). I have also tested the same locally and it works perfectly. Try updating your IPython.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly how to execute in Google Colab:

1. import IPython
2. Update IPython
3. Now able to *from IPython.display import GeoJson*

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue to be caused by your Collab runtime having an older version of IPython installed.

```
pip freeze
```

Output

```
ipython==5.5.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipython-sql==0.3.9
ipywidgets==7.5.1
```

Since the collab was created sometime ago

Updating the module fixed the issue for me

```
pip install -U IPython
```

After which you can restart your runtime and the changes should be reflected

```
pip freeze
```

Output

```
ipython==7.16.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipython-sql==0.3.9
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, since I'm using Google Colab though I didn't mark as answer since colab needs ! before pip commands - didn't want to confuse people trying this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Google Colaboratory has an older version of IPython installed (`v5.5.0` as of the time I'm writing this). The best way to fix this is to include the following line in the Colab notebook before your `import` statements:

```
!pip3 install --upgrade IPython
```

This should fix it for you!